# Ag-grid filter menu automatically resizing

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid

**Looking how to make the filter menu of ag-grid automatically resizing (depending of contents).**


Here there's an [exemple](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fnf3fUirXOGiE4er)
with tooltips for the columns B and C.
In [Column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ2GU.png) i would make a larger menu without fixing the width (then i can apply the code in other columns).
Maybe by changing the css classes `ag-filter-virtual-list-container` and `ag-filter-virtual-list-item`

Answer (score 0):

Use Material UI popover component. It'll automatically resizes.[Material UI PopOver](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i prefer to use the default filter menu of ag-grid in this case, some CSS code can handle this problem.